# Display hidden not working with flex in Tailwind

Tags: html, css, laravel, tailwind-css

I'm trying to hide a div in mobile, and display flex with md screen & above, here's my code:

```
<div class="hidden md:flex">
            <x-navbar.nav-links :href="route('welcome')"> Home </x-navbar.nav-links>
            <x-navbar.nav-links :href="route('welcome')"> Shop </x-navbar.nav-links>
            <x-navbar.nav-links :href="route('welcome')"> About Us </x-navbar.nav-links>
            <x-navbar.nav-links :href="route('welcome')"> Contact </x-navbar.nav-links>   
   </div>
```

Apparently, the div is hidden all the time whether it's a md or sm or xl screen
How can I fix this in Tailwind?

Comment: It is pretty simple, use chrome or firefox console, you can inspect in any width... and also see the active classes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem too and it is because of Chrome,
If you use

```
class="invisible md:visible md:flex"
```

It will work on Chrome

Comment: Yes, I meant Class. was working on Reactjs this morning. that's why.  but invisible has a problem that the tag can't be seen but it still affect the layout. So in this case I think we have to customs @media query css for it, to overwrite tailwind.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong.
The whole time I'm looking for bugs all over the place or thinking I made a mistake somewhere.
I realized that sometimes, the reason you don't see any change when you do

```
<div class="hidden md:block/flex/">
```

is because of ***Chrome***.
When I tested my page on a Firefox or Brave, it works just fine as expected.

Answer (score 1):

try the opposite:

```
<div class="flex max-md:hidden">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
<div class="hidden md:visible">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead :

```
<div class="hidden sm:flex">
```

or

```
<div class="invisible sm:visible">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: <div class="invisible h-0 sm:visible sm:h-auto">

Answer (score 0):

For me on nextJs (react), i've changed order import in my main component and it's work.

like this :

```
import NavBar from "@/shared/components/layout/navBar";
import "./globals.scss";
```

before :

```
import "./globals.scss";
import NavBar from "@/shared/components/layout/navBar";
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided seems correct.

Check if you're importing any CSS from any other NPM packages or locally, as there may be some conflicts in regard to css specificity.

For example, in a Next JS Project (layout.tsx):

```
import './globals.css';
import '@author/package/dist/index.css';
```

If present, navigate to your tailwind.config.ts file and add set "important" to true like so (important: true):

```
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss';

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {}
   },
  plugins: [],
  important: true, // <<<< HERE
};

export default config;
```

From Tailwind Docs

> The important option lets you control whether or not Tailwind’s utilities should be marked with !important. This can be really useful when using Tailwind with existing CSS that has high specificity selectors.

Source: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I then realized that I had not written this in the terminal after quitting and coming back :

> npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch

(replace input.css and output.css with your files)
It worked for me after! :)

Answer (score -1):

try to d' not make space between md and flex
hidden md:flex
not    md: flex

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

What I did was if you use a media query, first type the display type and then the rest of propeties. Otherwise it won't work.

[code picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgNeW.png)

Comment: Please review [answer] and [Please do not upload images of code/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1030169)